# How to get parameters from url after hash?

Tags: php

Need to get parameters after hash(#) just using PHP

https://app.edivo.io/alpha/1.0/callback.php#access_token=fdsfDRSgsfedfgwERvnfd

I want to get access_token=fdsfDRSgsfedfgwERvnfd from above url, only using PHP

Comment: the parameter after hash is not sent to the server, its a browser anchor

Comment: From what I know hash values are not sent by browser to server, if you can have some workaround with js try with it first.

Answer (score 3):

That part is called "fragment" and you can get it in this way:

```
$url=parse_url("Your URL");
echo $url["fragment"]; //This variable contains the fragment
```

In Java script

```
var type = window.location.hash.substr(1);
```

Comment: This would be possible if he submitted a URL with # to the parse_url function. But I assume he wants to read out the URL from the browser adress bar, where getting the part after # is not possible with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible from the adress bar itself, see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26944636/12020068

> hashtag (#...) URL parts cant be detected from PHP (server-side). For that, use JavaScript.